# Plone4 - I need an idea

Tags: plone, roles, zope

I need to build a system around a concept as follows:

Users have their objects, which are created by managers and by users themselves. Their objects are visible only to themselves. How to do it in broad way? What logic and mechanism I should choose?

I know this question is perhaps too broad but I am quite novice to development.

Comment: You are correct that your question is not really on topic for Stack Overflow (see the [FAQ]), so it'll probably be closed as such. What you are looking for is a workflow that restricts access to the `Owner` role only. You'll also need to change the object owner on creation when created by a manager. If you have more concrete questions in those directions, feel free to ask. But do try to research your questions first. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements can be easily solved by using the built-in user-folders of Plone.

You need to enable them in the security-part of the controlpanel via yourhost:8080/sitename/@@security-controlpanel 
(*Note*: If you are logged in and trying to see the change of the config afterwards, looking for your own urserfolder, you need to logout and login again, because the foldercreation-trigger is the 'first' login).

Every user gets its own folder then, where other users but Managers don't have have access to and additionally have access themselves to items Managers created in their folder, because the ownership of the user-folder belongs to the user.

Preferably set this configuration in your own product (plone-add-on/plugin), to make it reproducable programatically.